# Is possible define a pointer to a function which has "not" variable argument list e.g "bools"?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I know that I can make in C++ pointer to a function with variable argument list:

```
bool (*fun)(bool,...);
```

but I'm looking for construction could make a **pointer to any of below function**:

```
bool f(bool);
bool f(bool, bool);
bool f(bool, bool, bool);
bool f(bool, bool, bool, bool);
bool f(bool, bool, bool, bool /*etc. */);
```

Now I try to workaround this by pointer to function which get array of bools and size of array

```
bool (*f)(bool*, in);
```

but I cannot be sure that the array passed is at least that size as in size parameter.

Comment: You could `template<std::size_t N> bool f(std::array<bool, N>)`.  Also, I don't think `bool (*fun)(...)` will work, because it needs at least one argument before the ellipsis.

Comment: Do you want a function that takes a specific large number of `bool`s, or a function that takes an arbitrary number of arguments that are all `bool`?

Comment: I'm looking of a pointer to function which takes an arbitrary number of arguments that are all bool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways around it:

1. Pass a reference to array and template it on size. This way, you avoid array to pointer decay and lose no type information:

   ```
   template <size_t N> bool func(bool(*f)(bool(&arr)[N]));
   ```
2. Use `std::array` to get an array with value semantics:

   ```
   template <size_t N> bool func(bool(*f)(std::array<bool, N>));
   ```
3. Use a variadic template to allow the old signatures. This is likely overkill.

   ```
    template <typename ... Args, typename = std::enable_if_t<AllSame<bool, Args...>::value>>
    bool func(bool(*f)(Args...));

    template <typename T, typename ... Args>
    struct AllSame;
    template <typename T>
    struct AllSame<T> : public std::true_type{};
    template <typename T, typename Arg, typename ... Args>
    struct AllSame : public std::conditional_t<std::is_same<T, Arg>::value,
                            AllSame<T, Args...>,
                            std::false_type> {};
   ```